# Passenger: "Missing these required gems redgreen"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, passenger

total ruby newbie, trying to setup a Rails/MongoDB application on Mac OS X Snow leopard.

Installed Ruby 1.9.1 and RubyGems 1.3.7, `which ruby` and `which gem` point to the same directory. I'm using the Snow Leopard built-in apache and Passenger 2.2.11. I'm using the rails template from the [mongo-site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+-+Getting+Started) which seems to work okay overall.

The exact error that passenger gives me is:

`/Users/User/Sites/feuerapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010. Use #requirement **Notice: C extension not loaded. This is required for optimum MongoDB Ruby driver performance. You can install the extension as follows: gem install bson_ext If you continue to receive this message after installing, make sure that the bson_ext gem is in your load path and that the bson_ext and mongo gems are of the same version. Missing these required gems: redgreen You're running: ruby 1.9.1.376 at /usr/local/bin/ruby rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/User/.gem/ruby/1.9.1, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 Run`rake gems:install`to install the missing gems.`

The weird thing is that redgreen is installed and looks fine to me:

`Dahlia:feuerapp User$ ls -la vendor/gems/

total 0

drwxr-xr-x   7 User  staff  238 May 18 22:56 .

drwxr-xr-x   5 User  staff  170 May 18 23:00 ..

drwxr-xr-x  11 User  staff  374 May 18 22:56 factory_girl-1.2.4

drwxr-xr-x  11 User  staff  374 May 18 22:56 mocha-0.9.8

drwxr-xr-x   7 User  staff  238 May 18 22:56 mongo_mapper-0.7.6

drwxr-xr-x   7 User  staff  238 May 18 22:56 redgreen-1.2.2

drwxr-xr-x  11 User  staff  374 May 18 22:56 shoulda-2.10.3`

Commenting out this line in environment.rb "solves" the issue, but that's not really want I want:

`config.gem 'redgreen'`

I don't understand anything of gems yet, but from my limited understanding, redgreen should be there and found?

Comment: Is there a reason you are explicitly calling redgreen from your environment? Most gems that use redgreen will call it themselves without the need of you explicitly doing it. I know this doesn't really answer your question, more of a curiosity :)

Comment: @theIV No idea, I'm just "blindly" following the provided template in the hope that these guys know what they are doing. I'm learning this stuff and just try to get a site up and running to start writing my first ruby app :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found it, I was missing the test-unit gem.

How I found it? I went to vendor/gems/redgreen-1.2.2/lib/redgreen.rb and looked at the "require" statements, which lists "test/unit". Quick googling led me to the test-unit gem, and after `gem install test-unit` it works now.

I'm not sure if I can tell rake somehow that there is a dependency and I'm a bit disappointed that there was no better error message, but at least that's resolved now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You are right in that the error message gave you no heads up as to what the hell was going on. :[

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not telling you that it's looking for a different version of the gem for whatever reason. If you run (sudo) rake gems:install and try again, do you get the same message? The gem dependency business is a bit of a pain in the ass, to say the least.

Also, in particular to this case, I would say that removing redgreen is not the end of the world. Since it's specific to testing, you could also move the gem dependency into the environments/test.rb (or whatever other testing environments are set up) and not have to deal with it in development/staging/production.

Any gems that are dependent on testing should only be specified for your testing environments and not for your entire application.

Comment: Yes, rake gems:install doesn't change anything. I've tried rm -rf vendor/gems and re-ran rake gems:install / rake gems:unpack. It unpacked the redgreen-1.2.2 gem.